# Java - Why doesn't my buttons show in the panel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I'm trying to learn `Java Swing`. Right now, I'm making a simple program and I need to make a button. I have two classes: driver and swing. 
I create the button and import the `javax.swing.JButton` and added the button. Finally, the button added to the panel but Idk why I just get the panel?
Can anyone help me, please? Here's my code:

```
 import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Swing extends JFrame {

    private JFrame f;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel panel; 

    public Swing() {
    }

    public Swing(String titleName) {
        creatButton();
        creatFrame(titleName);
    }

    public void creatButton() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("click me");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(btn);
        btn.setBounds(50, 100, 95, 30);
        add(panel);

    }

    private void creatFrame(String title) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400, 500);
        f.setLayout(null);

    }

}
public class Driver {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Swing ("calculator");
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not adding the button/panel to the frame at all. How do you expect it to be visible? I'd say instead of `JFrame f = new JFrame(title);` you want to use your `Swing` class.

Comment: I see a null layout , that couldn’t possible be causing issues

Comment: @Store shah First thing, do not use `null` layout.Second thing do not `setBounds` on button and add that panel as content pane of frame(which is your class). Third thing do not create another frame in your class. And call all method on your class  inside `createFrame` method. And also read the tutorial of [how to use layout manager in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,lets start with...

```
JButton btn = new JButton("click me");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(btn);
btn.setBounds(50, 100, 95, 30);
add(panel);
```

You:

- Create a button
- Create a panel
- You add the button to panel
- You add the panel to the frame

And then...

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("calculator");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new 
f.setVisible(true);
```

You create a brand new instance of `JFrame` and show it, but it has nothing on to it?! !

Instead, you should avoid extending from `JFrame` and maybe use `JPanel` instead, something like...

```
public class Swing extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;

    public Swing() {
        creatButton();
        add(button);
    }

    public void creatButton() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("click me");
    }
}
```

Then you can just create a window (or other container) and add it to it

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new Swing());
f.pack(); 
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

As a general rule, `JFrame` is a really poor extension point, it's a complex, compound component and locks you into a single use case.  It's generally a better idea to start with something `JPanel` which provides you with a lot more flexibility and a lot less complexity and is easily reusable.

You really, really, really need to avoid `null` layouts

Answer (score 0):

`creatFrame` is creating a new JFrame different than the frame itself (your Swing class extending JFrame).

Remove the line:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
```

and call the methods over `this` instead of `f`.